# Ubuntu installation unsuccessful in Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

I installed ubuntu from USB flash drive. I partitioned drives for swap, ram and home directories. I also partitioned 700 MB separate space for device bootloader. when nearing installation, I got an error saying "Device boot loader cannot be used and asked me to use a different one. After I selected that got message saying installation is successful. But, after restarting my computer I don't see a prompt to choose between ubuntu and windows. I do not see that in my Control Panel either.

ps: The iso installer in my USB drive was no more but, I saw files unpacked. Any Help?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: try boot-repair.

Comment: I am not able to loginto UBUNTU

Comment: _"... I do not see that in my Control Panel either..."_, what *Control Panel*?!

Comment: windows control panel. won't see that there?

Comment: never tried installing Ubuntu within Windows with Wubi... I wonder if boot-repair disk works for Wubi installs of Ubuntu... sorry couldn't help...

Comment: a little on [Pros and Cons of Wubi](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/wubi-pros-and-cons) you might want to know with your future installs...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting from the USB again, and then using boot-repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I am not seeing Ubuntu in control panel ADD/Remove program. Is this say anything?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a program that gets installed within Windows, it is its own operating system, separate from Windows. You will not see anything Ubuntu related from within Windows, except for when looking at your partitioning scheme, which you can view by following these steps http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/305